# place python script in chef cookbook

Tags: python, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a python script which deploys ear file on a server, how do I execute this script using chef to bootstrap a linux node?

Tried a recipe like below, but it couldn't identify my python script which is present inside "mycookbook\files\default\deploy.py" folder of my cookbook.

```
execute 'executeFile' do
 command "python #{'deploy.py'}"
end
```

Tried giving full file path still it didn't recognise the file. How to execute a python script inside a cookbook using execute resource of chef?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `poise-python` cookbook's `python_execute` resource:

```
cookbook_file "/root/deploy.py" do
  source "deploy.py"
end

python_execute "/root/deploy.py"
```

You could also use a normal `execute` resource if you tweak the command line. The important bit is you need to use `cookbook_file` to actually copy out the file from the cookbook to somewhere on the node.

Comment: Thank you, this helped to solve the issue. Can I pass chef attributes to python file? Like in chef "cookbook_file node['py']['tmpDir'] do" will resolve to proper location based on attributes entry, can I access these attributes in python file as well?

Comment: No, you would have to pass any values you want as command line arguments: `python_execute "/deploy.py #{node['whatever']}"`